# What Runtime gc actually does and what is causing this output?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Does it forces thread scheduler to pick up gc thread for execution or it simply plays with priority of gc thread?

```
class Test1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Test1 test = new Test1();
test = null;
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
System.out.println("in main after gc...");


public void finalize()
{
 System.out.println("in finalize method...");

}
}
```

Output possibility 1: 
in finalize method...
in main after gc...

Output possibility 2:
in main after gc...
in finalize method...

Output possibility 1: explanation:
This output is possibly caused because "Runtime.getRuntime().gc()" made gc thread to execute which printed first line after which main thread was picked up and printed the second line.

Output possibility 2: explanation:
What is causing this output? 
Is it because "Runtime.getRuntime().gc()" made priority of gc thread high so that main thread continued for some time after which gc thread was picked up?

Comment: I believe it's implementation specific but I think gc "suggests" a garbage collection. A suggestion that's usually ignored (because the JVM knows what it's doing and telling it when to garbage collect is usually a bad idea)

Comment: There is no garantee of when finalise will be called so either of those scenarios could happen either with or without calling gc

Comment: You should not use finalizers except as a debugging tool. You cannot rely on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does `Runtime.gc()` actually do?

In theory it could do a variety of things.  For example:

- It may cause the garbage collector to run NOW, pausing the current thread until it has completed.
- It may do absolutely nothing.
- It may do something else; e.g. trigger a GC at the opportunity, or increase the priority of the GC threads.

There is sufficient (deliberate) ambiguity in spec that it is not possible to say whether a `gc()` call will cause a particular object to be collected.  Certainly, not for all of the ways / all of the platforms where you could run the application.

You seem to be interested / concerned with the timing of the `finalize`.  The "bad news" is that even if you know that a particular `gc()` is going to find that a given object is unreachable, you the cannot be sure that it will be finalized before the `gc()` call completes.

In fact, when a typical HotSpot GC finds an unreachable object that is finalizable, it enqueues it to be finalized AFTER the GC cycle.  The object won't be deleted yet.

---

Therefore, the actual output from the above *could be* any of the following:

1. One message:

   ```
     in main after gc
   ```
2. Two messages:

   ```
     in main after gc
     in finalize method
   ```
3. Two messages in the other order

   ```
     in finalize method
     in main after gc
   ```

Case one will occur if either the gc() call is ignored, or if the JVM exits before the JVM processes the finalization queue.

Case two is the most likely behavior for current generation JVMs.

Case three could occur if the something else triggers a GC before this `gc()` call happens.  It could also occur in a (hypothetical) Java implementation where finalization happens synchronously with the garbage collection.